# Chrome OS instead of Splashtop OS

Tags: google-chrome-os, hp-mini

I have an HP Mini 110 with Splashtop OS as an 'instant on' OS. I've updated to the newest version which has a Chromium browser...and not too much else

You know what would be really cool? The newest Chromium/Chrome OS build on there instead

Can someone in the know tel me if this is even possible?

(just to be clear, I don't want to put Chrome OS on my hard drive or boot to a USB drive. I want Chrome OS installed in the same place that Splashtop is installed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  It's also possible to put other operating systems into the flash chips that provide the (almost) "instant on" experience.

To be possible, the OS must fit in the size of the flash memory and run on that hardware.  Since ChromeOS is also based on top of Linux the answer is yes.

How do you get it on there, that I'm not sure.